# Flutter startup_namer sample

Tags: dart, flutter

I was trying out flutter and after following the steps to set up the environment ran a test drive successfully as described here.
https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/#vscode

Upon following the instructions at "Write your first flutter App" (https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/), I face errors upon copying the code given there at the very first step.  [image]

Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor`. It looks like you're using an outdated Flutter version.

Comment: What @GünterZöchbauer said + check whether you imported the material package.

Comment: Flutter doctor  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rtyq.png

Comment: Updating flutter did the trick